# Problems while writing decimal doubles onto a .csv file C++

Tags: c++, csv

I have a program that reads a test .csv file row by row and gives the standard deviation & mean of every row. It then goes on to write a new .csv file including the SD, average, and original values of every row.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#define rows 100
#define columns 11
using namespace std;
void read(int data[rows][columns]) {
string str;
    ifstream ifile;
    string filename="testDataIn.csv";
    ifile.open(filename);
    if (ifile)
    {
        int i = 0;
        while (getline (ifile,str)){
            stringstream ss(str);
            string temp;
            for(int j=0;j<columns;j++){
                getline(ss,temp,',');
                data[i][j]=atoi(temp.c_str());
            }
            i++;
        }
        cout << "Finished reading data." << endl;
    }else
    {
        cout << "Error reading." <<endl;
    }
    ifile.close();
}
double* avg(int data[rows][columns]){
    int total;
    double average[rows];
    for(int i=0;i<rows;i++){
        total=0;
        for(int j=0;j<columns;j++){
            total+=data[i][j];
        }
        average[i]=(double)total/columns;
        cout<<"The average of row "<<i+1<<" is "<<average[i]<<"."<<endl;
    }
    return average;
}
double* SD(int data[rows][columns]){
    int total;
    double sdarray[rows];
    double sdnum[columns];
    double sdtotal;
    for(int i=0;i<rows;i++){
        total=0;
        sdtotal=0;
        for(int j=0;j<columns;j++){
            total+=data[i][j];
        }
        for(int n=0;n<columns;n++){
            sdnum[n]=pow((data[i][n]-(double)total/columns),2);
        }
        for(int m=0;m<columns;m++){
            sdtotal+=sdnum[m];
        }
        sdarray[i]=(double)sqrt(sdtotal/columns);
        cout<<"The standard deviation of row "<<i+1<<" is "<<sdarray[i]<<"."<<endl;
    }
    return sdarray;
}
void write(int data[rows][columns],double* average, double* sdarray){
    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open("testDataOut.csv");
    if (myfile.is_open()) {
        for(int i=0;i<rows;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<columns;j++){
                myfile<<data[i][j]<<",";
            }
            myfile<<(double)average[i]<<","<<(double)sdarray[i];
            myfile<<"\n";
        }
        myfile.close();
        cout<<"Done writing to file.";
    }else{
        cout<<"Error writing.";
    }
}
int main()
{
    int data[rows][columns]={0};
    read(data);
    write(data,avg(data),SD(data));
    return 0;
}
```

The sole issue with this program is that the standard deviation and average of each row, when printed onto a .csv file, is random decimal gibberish, with the odd exception of a few rows.
[image: output of program in .csv]
I'm not sure why, I simply can't figure this one out.

Comment: Drag the separator between columns to make them wider. A series of # signs is simply Excel's way of saying the value is wider than the column and cannot be shown for that reason.

Comment: With the `return average;` you are returning the address of local a variable. Probably not the best thing to do.

Comment: Don't start with the entire data set at once. Start with a small file with three numbers. Then step through your code to see where it's going wrong.

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik I know, but those values are gibberish like 3.46212e-317, so I didn't bother. They're useless and not the result of what I expected to happen. :P

Comment: @Ron My complier did notify me about that. What would you suggest I do instead?

Comment: @NamelessKing Rethink the approach, loose the pointers and as others have pointed out - start small and use the debugger.

Comment: @NamelessKing> so your compiler already pointed at your mistake. No reason to ask what happens, it told you already. As for returning the address of a local variable, let's state it clearly: it will **not** work. The result of using that pointer is undefined, it might crash your program, corrupt your file, you name it. Most likely is simply that the memory is re-used for something else so what you read from it looks like garbage.

Comment: @spectras Ah, it was a warning. I suppose I should take warnings from compilers seriously. :P Thanks guys.

Comment: Very seriously. In fact, all compilers have an option to upgrade warnings to errors, and most if not all serious projects enable it. Typical compilation command includes `-Wall -Wextra -Werror`. Without those, anything the compiler *understands* will compile, regardless of whether what it understood makes sense. With those flags, the compiler will detect a (large) list of common mistakes and warn you.

Comment: Use containers to store data and explore the `<algorithm>` facilities.

Comment: By the way, if you're using C++ you should not manipulate raw arrays. C++ has built-in collections, like `std::array` (fixed-size array) `std::vector` (dynamic array), `std::list`, … And those you can just return by value from your function. Compiler will even be smart enough to avoid the copy.